# appending list error typeerror sequence item o: expecting string, list found

Tags: python, regex, list, join, append

this is my code. basicily i think it should work like this self.list makes a ordered list self.contents turns a list into a string so i can display self.list in a scrollable window with self.plbuffer.set_text(self.contents). then os.walk traverses the directory defined in top than findall takes what i write in self.search finds the pattern in filenames and then it should be appended to self.list.

```
class mplay:
   def search_entry(self, widget):
    self.list = []
    self.contents = "/n".join(self.list)
    self.plbuffer.set_text(self.contents)
    search = self.search.get_text()
    top = '/home/bludiescript/tv-shows'
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top):
      for filename in filenames:
        if re.findall(filename, search):
         self.list.append(os.path.join([dirpath, filename]))
```

what does this error mean can i not append to self.list  using os.path.join

```
error =   file "./mplay1.py" , line 77 in search_entry 
          self.contents = "/n".join(self.list) line 
          typeerror sequence item o: expecting string, list found
```

Comment: This code won't run. Either give us the class or clean it up so it runs... What is the error?

Comment: ok class and full error text is added this is just part of the whole program. the program itself loades its when i use the search_entry function that i get the error

Comment: You are missing a : on your second last line...

Comment: that was a typo its there in my file

Answer (score 1):

The list must be a list of strings for it to work:

```
"/n".join(["123","123","234"]) # works
"/n".join([123, 123, 234]) #error, this is int
```

You also get an error if it is a list of lists, which is probably the case in yours:

```
"/n".join([[123, 123, 234],[123, 123, 234]]) # error
```

Throw in a print self.list to see what it looks like.

When you say it runs fine elsewhere, probably that is because the content of the list is different.

Also, note that joining an empty list [] will return an empty string, so that line is effectively doing nothing.

Comment: but it works in another part of my program that particular line

Comment: Probably because in that other part it is actually operating on a string. What are you trying to do with that line? Separate the items in the list with a new line character and join them into a new string?

Comment: so your saying it should self.contents = append("\n", self.list)

Comment: the line is there becuase .set_text function of pygtk will not except a list to be displayed  the other part of the program that uses it looks liek this  def file_ok_sel(self, w):
                print "%s" % self.filew.get_filename()
                self.list.append(self.filew.get_filename())
                self.contents = "\n".join(self.list)
                self.plbuffer.set_text(self.contents)

Comment: It all comes down to what is in self.list, string, integer or a list of lists. Did you try to print self.list or print type(self.list) before that line? What does it give you?

Comment: the contents both times should be filenames with a file path. so i did print self.list and im not sure what it would be its not a list of list i know that. this is one line '/home/bludiescript/tv-shows/[IB] Yumekui Merry - 1-13 [720p]', '[IB] Yumekui Merry - 01v3 [720p] [6F9716E7].mkv'], im assuming by the why its listed that its two entries

Comment: That is not what it is getting in your code. Right now it is getting an empty list.